# Calculate the area of two separate geometries in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, area, zero

I have been stumped on this problem for a while now and was wondering if anyone would be able to help.  So let's say I have a binary image as shown below and I would like to count the black elements (`zero`).  The problem is I want to know the number of elements associated with 'background' and 'trapezoid' in the middle individually, so output two values.  What would be the easiest way to approach this?  I have been trying to do it without using a `mask` but is that even possible?  I have the `numpy` and `scipy` libraries if that helps.

[image]

Comment: A hand-made numpy solution will depend on the assumptions about the shape / number of regions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two functions from [`scipy.ndimage.measurements`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.measurements): `label` and `find_objects`.

First you invert the array, because `label` function considers zero to be the background.

```
inverted = 1 - binary_image_array
```

Then you call `label` to find the different regions:

```
labeled_array, num_features = scipy.ndimage.measurements.label(inverted)
```

So, for *this particular array*, where you *already know* there are exactely two black blobs, you have the two regions in `labeled_array`.

Comment: So how would access the size of each blob?  Would I use `find_objects`?

Comment: You can use something like this: `count = labeled_array[labeled_array == label_number].astype(int).sum()`. This will create a boolean array, convert it to int, and sum every occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the scipy approach is a good answer.

I was thinking that you might be able to work with `numpy.cumsum` and `numpy.diff` to find an enclosed area.

The cumulative sum will be zero while you are in the black area, then increase by one for every pixel in the white area, be stable again while you traverse the enclosed area, then start increasing again, etc.

The second order difference then finds places where the jumps occur, and you are left with a "classified" map. No guarantee that this generalizes, just an idea.

```
a = numpy.zeros((10,10))
a[3:7,3:7] = 1
a[4:6, 4:6] = 0

y = numpy.cumsum(a, axis=0)
x = numpy.cumsum(a, axis=1)

yy= numpy.diff(y, n=2, axis=0)
xx = numpy.diff(x, n=2, axis=1)

numpy.dot(xx,yy)

array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```